# How to Add a fragment into an Activity using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

How to add a `Fragment` to an `Activity` using `jetpack compose`, i couldn't able to find a proper documentation , Here is my activity code looks like

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ComposeDemoTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    RenderTextUserFields()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And i have a fragment name `LoginFragment` i want to render the `LoginFragment` when the Application initially loaded then i want to navigate to Another Fragment I have `DetailsFragment`

Comment: If you are using Fragments, then you will need a View-based host, and the Fragment would host the Composable. Trying to use Fragment with `ComponentActivity.setContent {` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard `AppCompatActivity`:

For example in a `Scaffold` you can use something like:

```
   findNavController().navigate(R.id.nav_profile, bundle)
   scope.launch {
       scaffoldState.drawerState.close()
   }
```

with:

```
private fun findNavController(): NavController {
        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        return navHostFragment.navController
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering , but i wanted to compose way to add fragment like other view

Comment: @AbhijitChakra *a compose way*. Well, the real answer should be "why are you trying to use a Fragment in Compose".

Comment: you are right it's not required but i want to do it for a special senario is it possible

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend if you are using Fragments with JetpackCompose, to avoid using Activities.
So if if i understood correctly what you could do is define your **NavigationGraph**, which you can do by adding a navigation folder to your res folder, and there create `nav_graph.xml`(see: [Android Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)).
Set your initial fragment(in this case LoginFragment) as a starting fragment(this can be done in the design of nav_graph.xml after you add your fragments to it).
After that you can declare your nav controller in a fragment with for example `val navController = findNavController()` which you can pass into your composable, and upon a click or whatever you have you navigate to the desired fragment(which has to be defined in `nav_graph.xml`).
There are two ways to do this:

1. You can just call `navController.navigate(R.id.yourFragmentId)`
2. Or you can define a action between LoginFragment and DetailsFragment in `nav_graph.xml`(you can just connect them in the design view), and then later navigate with `navController.navigate(R.id.loginToDetailActionId)`